# Next JS 13.4.7 using router scroll false not working

Tags: next.js, router

Here my code. I want to do a update url params function by next router, and I set the scroll flag to false, but not work.

Expect update the url params, and will not scroll to the top.

```
export default function Redirect() {
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleRedirect = (url) => {
        router.replace(url, { scroll: true });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=\> handleRedirect("https://xxxxxxx")}\>redirect\</button\>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you removed the backslash from the button opening tag yet ? 
`<button onClick={()=\> handleRedirect("https://xxxxxxx")}\>`